# jQuery trigger() with Custom Event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with some code (written by someone else) that is something like the following:

```
var _layoutRoot = $("#whatever");

eventName = 'CopyArticle';
eventData = { targetArticleIds: selectedArticleIds, targetCategoryIds: selectedCategoryIds };

// fire the event
if (eventName) // null is unexepcted here
    _layoutRoot.trigger(eventName, eventData);
```

I just don't know enough about what this means.

I can see that `trigger` causes the named event to happen. But since when is there a JavaScript `CopyArticle` event? How is this a valid event and how would it be handled?

Comment: jQuery [allows custom events](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just attach your custom event to an element with `on`.  To fire the event use `trigger`.  You can pass extra arguments to the trigger function using an array.

**HTML**

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#test").on("customEvent", function(e,msg){
  alert(msg);
});
var dataToPass = "This is a msg";
$("#test").trigger("customEvent", [dataToPass]);
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/85wjt/1/

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I searched the project and can't find `on.('CopyArticle` or `on.("CopyArticle`. Perhaps a variable is used somehow.

Comment: try `_layoutRoot.on(CopyArticle, function(e,obj){});` then trigger with: `_layoutRoot.trigger(eventName, [eventData]);`

Comment: Not sure I followed that. This is an enormous .NET project. If there is an existing event handler for `CopyArticle`, then it seems like a project search on either `on.('CopyArticle` or `on.("CopyArticle` would find it.

Comment: @JonathanWood Maybe the author uses `.bind()` method instead. Also using `.`  is syntactically wrong here, `.on('CopyArticle`.

Comment: @KevinBowersox: I don't think you follow me. I understood the usage from your original answer. As I said in my question, this is an existing project. If it works as you say, I should be able to find a handler for it. You showing me how it works in more detail doesn't address this point.

Answer (score 2):

As per the jquery [website](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

> When we define a custom event type using the .on() method, the second
>   argument to .trigger() can become useful. For example, suppose we have
>   bound a handler for the custom event to our element instead of the
>   built-in click event as we did above:

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "custom", function( event, param1, param2 ) {
  alert( param1 + "\n" + param2 );
});
$( "#foo").trigger( "custom", [ "Custom", "Event" ] );
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery allows you to fire an event of any name you want

```
$(".foo").on("some:custom:event", function(event) {
  console.log("hello");
});

$(".foo").trigger("some:custom:event");

// hello
```